# How do I properly use NetExport's "showPreview" option in an automated script? (Webdriver w/ Firebug & NetExport)

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, firebug, har, netexport

I am currently using Selenium Webdriver with Firefox (and the Firebug/NetExport plug-ins) to fulfill a regression testing scenario where a specific query string parameter that is pulled from an HTTP request sent after a user utilizes a search bar on the page. After the call has been made, NetExport saves the .HAR files from the request to a local folder. Actually, it saves 3 files (one for each page visited during the test), even though I have the code to capture the traffic directly before the last page loading...but that's a different issue.

However, I need to automate this a bit more to do the following:

1) Load the captured HAR file to a readable format
2) Find the value needed 
3) Record that value for review later

My first attempt to do this was to research how to drag and drop the HAR file from a local folder to an online HAR viewer. This particular page has a box to either copy/paste the contents of the HAR file, or drag and drop it in the text box to generate the preview. I've read several different questions about this (some from stackoverflow), and decided that it is either not possible or would be complicated and not practical.

Enter the "showPreview" preference. On several different sites, it is described like this: "**Show Preview:** *Show a preview of exported data. HAR Viewer is used by default. See  **extensions.firebug.netexport.viewerURL** preference.*"

This gave me the idea that I can just have NetExport automatically just kick the HAR file into a viewer that opens in a new tab...but I can't find any simplified instructions on how this is supposed to happen. One support page gave an answer to use **profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.netexport.viewerURL", "http://www.softwareishard.com/har/viewer1-1/");**  however, I have updated that URL to point to the newest one, and have this preference loaded...but no matter what I do, I cannot get a preview of the HAR file to appear in a new Firefox tab, or anywhere else for that matter.

I'm out of ideas. I'm fairly new to this, so answers or tips that some people have given on other somewhat-related questions are above my level of understanding, and don't seem to fit anyways.

At any rate, here's what I have so far. Please ignore the commented out stuff at the bottom - it's just stuff I'm trying, and wanted to keep in there for reference in the event that I wanted to tinker with it again.

---

```
package scn01pkg;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.lang.InterruptedException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class UsingBMP {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

        // auto-install FireBug and NetExport into Firefox profile
        File firebug = new File("firebug-2.0.11-fx.xpi");
        File netExport = new File("netExport-0.9b7.xpi");

        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        try {
            profile.addExtension(firebug);
            profile.addExtension(netExport);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Setting Firebug preferences
        profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.currentVersion", "2.0.11");
        profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.addonBarOpened", true);
        profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.console.enableSites", true);
        profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.script.enableSites", true);
        profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.net.enableSites", true);
        profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.previousPlacement", 1);
        profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.allPagesActivation", "on");
        profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.onByDefault", true);
        profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.defaultPanelName", "net");

        // Setting netExport preferences
        profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.netexport.alwaysEnableAutoExport", true);
        //  ---profile under this comment is a test---
        profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.netexport.viewerURL", "http://www.softwareishard.com/har/viewer/");
        profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.netexport.autoExportToFile", true);
        profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.netexport.Automation", true);
        profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.netexport.showPreview", true);
        profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.netexport.defaultLogDir", "C:\\workspace\\CaptureNetworkTraffic");


        // Launch Firefox with the desired capabilities
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
        capabilities.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.ANY);
        capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

        // Wait until Firebug is loaded - 5s
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 

        // Load tested website mainpage
        driver.get("http://www.website.com");

        // Wait for page to load (10s)
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Clicking "Login" from the main page
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login-block a")).click();

        // Wait until tested website's login page is loaded - 10s
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Enter username
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("myusername");

        // Waiting after entering in Username, 5s (increase if script failing persists)
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 

        // Enter password
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("mypassword");

        // Clicking "Sign in" after entering UN and PW
        driver.findElement(By.name("loginbutton")).click();

        // Waiting for page to load - implicitly wait 10s
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    

        // Capture traffic
        try {
            //arbitrary wait time to avoid "issues"
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            //searching for product
            driver.findElement(By.id("parts")).sendKeys("searchterm");
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#keyword-button-div button")).click();

            //Time to process request, print to file, and quit.
            Thread.sleep(6000);
            } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
            }

        //  ------Last bit commented out until proper use is determined--------

        // Extra wait time - uncomment out if needed
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Load the HAR viewer website
        //driver.get("http://www.softwareishard.com/har/viewer/");

        // Wait for page to load
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Upload file to the online HAR viewer
        //WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=sourceEditor]"));
        //WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.id("sourceEditor"));
        //inputField.sendKeys("C:\\workspace\\CaptureNetworkTraffic\\www.freescale.com+2015-08-24+11-23-46.har");

        // Wait 2 seconds
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Submit the data
        // driver.findElement(By.name("appendPreview")).click();

        // Wait for page to load
        // driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // ---------uncomment out when script is working to this point--------------
        // driver.quit();


        }
}
```

---

Thank you in advance to anyone who takes the time to read my wall of text!

Answer (score 1):

Lacking any additional suggestions or support, I managed to solve my issue with a lengthy "taking 3 left turns instead of 1 right turn" approach by:

1) In my code, have it open the online HAR viewer.

2) Saving the HAR files to a folder and being unable to change the default name or limit the export to just the one I want, I note the default pixel location where the folder is opened AND the default pixel location of the THIRD HAR file in the list.

2) Utilize a very short AutoIt script to open the HAR export storage folder, which by default, overlays itself partially over the online HAR viewer drop box (where one would manually drop the file), then have the script manually drag and drop the third HAR file in the list to the drop box.

AutoIT code to drag and drop is as follows:

```
;~ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;~ ACTIONS - Open the folder location that contains the HAR files, then waits for Windows to process the action.
;~           Folder will open on top of the web page loaded before, which will leave the box area open
;~           to drag and drop the file
;~ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Run("C:\WINDOWS\EXPLORER.EXE /n,/e,C:\AutoIT\EXE\STORAGE\FOLDER")
Sleep(5000)

;~ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;~ ACTIONS - Go to pixel location of the THIRD HAR file in the list, then click and drag it to the pixel location
;~           located within the drop box area of the webpage
;~---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

MouseClickDrag("left", -716, 292, 280, 261)
```

The AutoIt script must be compiled into an .exe, and then using the following code to call it

```js
try {
  Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
  Process p2 = r.exec("C:\\Default\\HAR\\STORAGE\\FOLDER\\LOCACTION\\MyAutoItScript.Exe");              
} catch(IOException ex) {
  System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

As long as the folder isn't already open and any previously exported HAR files are in the storage folder, it will grab the correct HAR file and drop it in the box. I wish I could find a better solution, but at this point I'll take the extremely long and hard way over no solution at all!